# How to append to a nested dictionary inside a function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

Suppose I have a dataframe with different columns that I want to compare. If the column value is greater than 0, I want to add the index, column name, and value to a dictionary.

```
# Test dataframe
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'Pop_Diff':[0, 0, 20], 'HU_Diff':[10, 0, 20], 'Area_Diff': [20, 10, 0]},index='1 2 3'.split())
```

[image]

To do this, I have created a function that will look at each row and write to a dictionary.

```
county_diffs = dict()

def mismatch_county(row):
    pop_diff = row.Pop_Diff
    hu_diff = row.HU_Diff
    area_diff = row.Area_Diff
    item_id = row.name
    if (pop_diff > 0) | (hu_diff > 0) | (area_diff > 0):
        if pop_diff > 0:
            print(item_id)
            print(str(pop_diff))
            county_diffs.setdefault(item_id, {'pop_diff': pop_diff})

        elif hu_diff > 0:
            print(item_id)
            print(str(hu_diff))
            county_diffs.setdefault(item_id, {'hu_diff': hu_diff})

        elif area_diff > 0:
            print(item_id)
            print(str(area_diff))
            county_diffs.setdefault(item_id, {'area_diff': area_diff}) 

test_df.apply(mismatch_county, axis=1)
```

With the above function, when I `print(county_diffs)`, I get `{'1': {'hu_diff': 10}, '2': {'area_diff': 10}, '3': {'pop_diff': 20}}`. What I want is this: `{'1': {'hu_diff': 10, 'area_diff': 20}, '2': {'area_diff': 10}, '3': {'pop_diff': 20, 'hu_diff': 20}}`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by transposing and using `to_dict()` method, you'll get a dictionary close to your output:

```
>>> county_diffs = test_df.T.to_dict()
>>> print(county_diffs)
{'1': {'Pop_Diff': 0, 'HU_Diff': 10, 'Area_Diff': 20},
 '2': {'Pop_Diff': 0, 'HU_Diff': 0, 'Area_Diff': 10},
 '3': {'Pop_Diff': 20, 'HU_Diff': 20, 'Area_Diff': 0}}
```

Now, in your nested dictionaries, just filter out the keys (representing columns) where values are equal 0 (that's the `if value` part in the dict comprehension):

```
>>> county_diffs = {index: {column: value for column, value in county_diffs[index].items() if value} for index in county_diffs}
>>> print(county_diffs)

{'1': {'HU_Diff': 10, 'Area_Diff': 20},
 '2': {'Area_Diff': 10},
 '3': {'Pop_Diff': 20, 'HU_Diff': 20}}
```

Comment: @gwydion93 does that help?

Comment: Yes, that did it!. Apologies for taking so long to mark this as correct!